# Conference uk visa

Tags: visas, uk, applications, proof-provenance-of-funds

Please help out
I’m a student and I want to use my mom as my sponsor, she works but her salary is low And I think she almost spend all each month, my dad is retired on pension, can my dad transfer money in her account for about 3 months or recently for me to apply? Does my dad also have to prove where his money’s from? Cause he can’t, they are deposits from local businesses. The question I think is does my dad transferring into my moms account legal and won’t be viewed as suspicious 
Thanks!

Comment: If your father’s money is lawfully obtained it is of course legal for him to transfer it to whomever he likes. However, from a UKVI point of view, he would need to be able to prove the source of the funds, and they typically view as suspicious sudden unusual transfers of money just before a visa application is made. See ‘funds parking’ https://travel.stackexchange.com/questions/92121/uk-visa-refusal-on-v-4-2-a-c-and-sometimes-e

Comment: Can he send money to my mom for 3 months before I apply? His business is a church owner which is registered, but my country don’t collect taxes from them and he doesn’t receive salary from this church, his bank statement only reflects his pension and some deposits from individuals

Answer (score 0):

I have got UK Visa twice for conference, You need to satisfy ECO that you have strong social and financial ties with your home country. Considering you as a student you first need to give a good reason in your cover letter, why its important for you attend the conference.
Regarding funding sources as you are a student and you may not have 3000 GBP plus into your account. You can attach your mother bank statement but your father needs to send a consistent amount to your mother's bank account and in transaction description, he should write "Pocket Money / Household expenses". This may still arise a question 1) She needs to prove the funding in her account 2) you need to attach your mother tax documents.

Its very important that your financial status is crystal clear and ECO should not have any reason to doubt about money parking or any other scenario.

If your father is a business person he needs to declare his business documents, bank statements and everything. Unfortunately, there is no other way around to this.

Comment: Can he send money to my mom for 3 months before I apply? His business is a church owner which is registered, but my country don’t collect taxes from them and he doesn’t receive salary from this church, his bank statement only reflects his pension and some deposits from individuals